# Why list() with an object shows different results respectively?

Tags: python, list

The outcome is `None` with `list(a)` the second time. Anyone have a clue on that?

```
>>> test = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> a= test.iterkeys()
>>> list(a)
**[1, 3]**
>>> list(a)
**[]**
>>> list(a)
[]
```

Comment: its an iterable, once you consume the values they are gone.

Comment: Because `.iterkeys` returns a single pass iterator.

Answer (score 7):

`iterkeys` returns an *iterator*, which, as any iterator, can be iterated over *only once*.

`list` consumes the whole iterator, so that the latter can't provide any more values, so the subsequent lists are empty.